# AWS DynamoDB PutItem without authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it technically possible to use DynamoDB PutItem without doing authentication?
(public access)

Comment: No ideas? Come on...

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. It doesn't have the same public access that S3 provides. The owner of a DynamoDB table needs to explicitly  grant access to the table using IAM policies.

Comment: There is no way to make have an unauthenticated table, but you can accomplish this type of behavior by using Cognito to authenticate guest users. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28127937/627727) for a some context and links about implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have unauthenticated access to a Table in Dynamo DB. You could, however, use [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) to provide guest access to unauthenticated users (different than unauthenticated access to Dynamo DB).